# Saving NSNumber in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

Using currentIndex as NSNumber and saving NSNumber in NSUserDefaults.

Using currentIndex to store bookmarked page in NSUserDefaults

And this is how I am saving currentIndex in NSUserdefaults:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setInteger:currentIndex forKey:@"currentIndex"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

If this is the right way of saving currentIndex in NSUserdefaults then how can i retrieve saved currentIndex in NSUserdefaults.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8):

The title says that you want **to store** a NSNumber, you should do that in this way:

*obj-c*

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:nsnumberObject forKey:@"nsNumberStored"];
```

*swift*

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(nsnumberObject, forKey:"nsNumberStored")
```

And then **to fetch** the NSNumber do this:

*obj-c*

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *nsNumberFetched = [defaults objectForKey:@"nsNumberStored"];
```

*swift*

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.objectForKey("nsNumberStored")
```

You can read the official documentation here [Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: did it help you @user1120133 ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `setInteger: forKey:` is used to store an `int`, not a `NSNumber`.  If you want to store a `NSNumber`, user `setObject: forKey:`.

In order to retrieve your stored data, use `objectForKey:` (or `integerForKey:` instead if you would rather use `int`'s).

Comment: Just to clarify, setInteger:forKey: is a conveniences method that takes you NSInteger and converts it into a NSNumber for you. Similarly integerForKey: is a converts your stored NSNumber into an NSInteger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the 'opposite' to get it back out

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSInteger currentIndex = [defaults integerForKey:@"currentIndex"];
```